# Query entries from custom post type in an ACF flexible content field

Tags: custom-post-types, php, advanced-custom-fields

I want to query a custom post type `cpt_locations` if the `office_locations` layout is selected in a flexible content field. I'm sure I have the standard syntax, but if I view the page it prints yes many times then hangs - as if it's looping infinitely. In my `content-page.php` I have:

```
if( get_row_layout() == 'office_locations' ):

    $args = array(
     'post_type'=> 'cpt_locations',
     'posts_per_page' => 10
    );              

    $locations = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $locations -> have_posts() ) {
            while ( $locations -> have_posts() ) {

                echo 'yes'; 

        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    wp_reset_query();

endif;
```

In `page.php` I'm already in a loop - is this the problem?:

```
<?php
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

        if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
            comments_template();
        endif;

    endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `$locations->the_post()` in your loop:

```
if ( $locations -> have_posts() ) {
    while ( $locations -> have_posts() ) {
        $locations->the_post(); // Needed

        echo 'yes'; 
    }
}
```

One of the things this function does is advance `$locations` to the next post. Without it `$locations->have_posts()` will just repeat infinitely for the first post.